# MySQL intercept insert with a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have the following tables:

Globals:

- `id` (Primary key, Int, Auto increment)

Table 1:

- `t1Id` (Primary key, Int)
- `date` (Key, Datetime)

I want the following behaviour, when I do `INSERT INTO table1 (date) VALUES(NOW())` for example, I want that:

- An `TRIGGER` gets called before the actual insert happens.
- In the trigger it will insert a new entry in `Globals` table.
- It will use that id as the `t1Id` for `Table 1`.
- The original `INSERT` will **now** happen with the value for `t1Id`.

This should effectively create a sort of global unique identifier for all tables that are to be effected by this trigger.

My knowledge about `TRIGGER`s is how to react on them and do stuff after the original trigger condition has been fulfilled (in this case the insert), but I do not know how to properly implement this specific behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_check AFTER INSERT ON table1
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Globals .... VALUES (NEW.t1Id)
   END;
```

Row `NEW` contains the row as soon inserted. And so `NEW.t1Id` will contain the latest id added.
I would remove the primary key on `Id` column of the `Globals` table.

For [details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html).